# What do I need to make my overhead garage door operable?

Tags: doors, garage

I bought this house and they remodeled the garage into a room. I’m slowly, but surely making it back into a garage.

It has a door, and the bar across the top of the garage.

Don’t I just need the motor and bar from the motor to the garage door?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you open the garage door with one hand, without strain? If you cannot, it is missing the door spring.

Comment: @crip659 The torsion spring is inside the tube.  You can see the tension adjust knobs on either end.

Answer (score 9):

Step 1, forget the automatic opener. *Place it out of your mind and never think of it again. Seriously.* "But I'll want a power opener!" Of course, but it's a distraction.  The door needs to work perfectly by hand before a power opener is possible.  Because openers don't actually lift doors. Counterweights do.

So you'll need to learn Garage Door 101 and figure out how counterweights work.

On this type of door, you notice the door rolls horizontal as it goes up. The door "weighs" nothing horizontal, so the counterweight must be variable. That's fine though; that's a perfect job for a spring.   Now I see a shaft with spools on both ends; around those go a tension cable on each side which attaches to the bottom of the door and runs alongside the track, typically on the outside of the track.

There is then a spring mechanism which acts on the horizontal shaft.  I'm wondering where your spring is hiding.  Your shaft is twice as thick as mine on a large 14x12' industrial door, so I'm wondering if the spring is inside the shaft. I would search all the garage door parts for markings and try to identify the manufacturer, and installer. The installer may be able to give your door a checkout and affirm it's intact.

I would also look carefully at the condition of the track, particularly whether the track is entirely present.  Because if I was decommissioning a garage door, I might deconstruct the horizontal part of the track.

If the door is working properly, you can easily move it up and down with one hand, and it will stay put at any position you place it at.  If it doesn't do that, *hear me on this* - get it fixed before you attach an opener.

Openers, at this point, bolt right up.  It is important that the opener act on the door, *never* horizontal rod.  It's not a hoist, it's part of the counterweight.  When a door is at full top position, it has no gravity acting on it, and is lethargic about coming down. If you try to force it by turning the shaft, all it does is slacken the lifting wires, which makes them hop off the spool and turn into a rat's nest. Then the door finally does move, it drops like a guillotine.

Answer (score 5):

Your door has a rather large bar or tube going across the top. Rather than the torsion bar or tube many of us are familiar with, I think yours is set up with springs concealed inside the tube. It looks a lot like the Wayne Dalton TorqueMaster product. Spring replacement and adjustment on these is obviously different to the procedures for the visible spring designs.

I've never worked on one of those, but by searching for "internal spring overhead door torsion tube" online I came across a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/qfuThoGGvV8) in which the removal and replacement of the spring is shown. Maybe it'll be informative for you.

I think you'll need to confirm that the door is not fixed to the wall anywhere, then confirm that the springs are providing force to help lift the door. This might require adjustment only, or possibly spring replacement also. After the door moves properly with manual operation you can consider installing an automatic opener -- the automatic opener cannot overcome a door that malfunctions when moved manually.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: yes.

To convert back to an automatic door, you only need to add a door opener plus the associated wiring (120V supply for the motor and low-voltage signal wires to/from the safety devices and operator pad.  Both are included with the opener.)

You already have an internal torsion spring above the door - you can see that by the adjusting knobs on either end of the spring tube.

The 120V wiring is already in place per your photo.  My guess is that the low voltage wiring was there, but was cut off by the previous owner of the house.  You may get lucky and find the wires in the wall, or you may need to run new ones.  That wire is almost always included in the retail pack along with the opener and track.

If you're relatively handy and have the required tools, expect it to take a weekend afternoon.  A second ladder will help immensely.